# Mapping using R

Tags: r, mapping

I have a dataset of 152,000 points in the NYC area. I've been having a hard time trying to build a plot of them in RStudio. [This](https://ssc442kirkpatrick.netlify.app/data/Rat_sightings.csv) is the data I'm working with. I've already dropped the location data that's missing. I've tried this among some other things to try to get it to work:

```
rat_stuff <- st_as_sf(rats_clean_1, coords = c("Latitude", "Longitude")
ggplot(rat_stuff) +
     geom_sf()
```

I've tried OpenStreetMap and some other things to try to make a map with all the plots on there, but nothing works. This is the first time I've tried to use R to map data, so I don't have any baseline code to work with.

How do I plot the points and generate some sort of heatmap with the rat sighting density?

Comment: What do you mean that "Nothing works"? Do you get an error message, or a blank plot? Your ggplot code works for me with your data (except you've got lat-long the wrong way round, and that stray point at about 77W).

Comment: In my console once I try to run the code the last line of my code disappears and nothing plots. How long did it take your system to plot everything?

Comment: About 10seconds on a 6yo laptop. Have you tried plotting the first 10 points? The first 100? The first 10,000? Is it a problem of size?

Comment: After when I try to turn the data into an sf object I get the following error:
```Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=38].
In addition: Warning message:
In if (nchar(dsn) < 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used``` 

I'm not sure why it worked for you and not for me.

Comment: You need to edit the question and explain what you did to get from your data file to that point. How did you create `rats_clean_1`? So your problem is nothing to do with `ggplot` because the error happens before then? Then remove that bit from your question too. We need to see the whole process that creates your error and no more, then we can maybe reproduce your error and work out why its not working.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

in_csv <- "D:\\downloads\\Rat_sightings.csv"

# read in CSV as sf object
rats_sf <- st_read(
              in_csv, 
              options=c("X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Longitude",
                        "Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Latitude")
           )

# set the coordinate reference system
st_crs(rats_sf) <- 4326

# uncomment to remove rows where no location is present in data
# rats_sf <- rats_sf[!(is.na(rats_sf$Location) | rats_sf$Location==""), ]

# plot points, coloured by borough
ggplot() +
    geom_sf(
      data=rats_sf, 
      aes(colour=Park.Borough)
    )
```

(Looks like you have a wayward observation)

[image]

```r
# density plot
ggplot() +
  geom_density_2d_filled(
                data=rats_sf, 
                aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)
  )
```

[image]

The density plot will likely look much better with the outlying point removed or corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I used `st_as_sf` to create my sf object. `st_read` did not work, as apparently that looks for either online database or a shapefile. Once the object was created I tried to plot the data. Unfortunately, when I turned the coordinates into the sf object it mutated my lat/long into a concatenated geometry field. `geom_sf` wouldn't let me use the geometry to plot the points, so I mutated Latitude into Lat and Longitude into Long so I could provide x/y coords. After that, it worked like a charm.

```
rats_clean <- rats_clean %>% drop_na("Latitude","Longitude","Location")

rats_clean <- rats_clean %>% 
     mutate(Lat = Latitude, Long = Longitude)

rats_sf <- st_as_sf(rats_clean, coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"), crs = 4326)

ggplot(data=rats_sf) +
   geom_sf() +
   geom_sf(data = rats_sf, aes(color = borough)) +
   coord_sf(xlim = c(-74.35,-73.65), ylim = c(40.45,40.95))

ggplot() +
  geom_density_2d_filled(
                data=rats_sf, 
                aes(x=Long, y=Lat))
```

Comment: I don't know why `st_read` did not work for you, I just fed it the CSV you supplied in your question. It's not possible to know what your original issue was as you don't indicate how you got from the CSV data to `rats_clean` (as pointed out by @Spacedman). I'm glad you got something working though. By the way, you probably don't need both calls to `geom_sf`, unless you plan to visualise the points differently twice in the same plot.